# SOLR - Missing configuration: Unsupported ContentType: text/html; Unsupported ContentType: application/pdf

Tags: pdf, search, solr, config

I have SOLR installed and running on Windows. I am following the Quick Start tutorial from the [SOLR website](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html#). Using the post.jar file I tried to index the documents listed under /solr/docs and I got the following erros -

```
ERROR - 2016-05-11 16:35:16.772; [c:gettingstarted s:shard2 r:core_node1 x:gettingstarted_shard2_replica1] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xe3 (at char #10, byte #-1)
```

I tried to index one file at a time, starting with a pdf and then tried a html. Below are the commands I used and the exceptions I see

```
java -Dc=gettingstarted -Dtype=application/pdf -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar scandocs/

ERROR - 2016-05-16 16:17:55.992; [c:gettingstarted s:shard2 r:core_node1 x:gettingstarted_shard2_replica1] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unsupported ContentType: application/pdf  Not in: [application/xml, application/csv, application/json, text/json, text/csv, text/xml, application/javabin]

java -Dc=gettingstarted -Dtype=text/html -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar scandocs/

ERROR - 2016-05-16 16:19:03.601; [c:gettingstarted s:shard2 r:core_node1 x:gettingstarted_shard2_replica1] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException; org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unsupported ContentType: text/html  Not in: [application/xml, application/csv, application/json, text/json, text/csv, text/xml, application/javabin]
```

All I have under the `/scandocs` fodler is a html file. 
It seems as if like my SOLR instance is not configured to read `html/pdf` documents. But the tutorial talks about indexing a bunch of rich documents without mentioning anything about the configuration.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with the configuration I need here.

Comment: The example posts to `update/extract `- what command are you using to index the files? The examples uses `bin/post`, not `post.jar` directly. The difference in the endpoint URL is important.in how Solr will attempt to process the submitted files.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue myself, the problem I had was that the post.jar tool you have to use in windows only uses the /update handler (as MatsLindh mentioned), which is very restrictive in how it indexes documents and only indexes certain file types, requires certain formatting etc.  Instead, I used the -Durl parameter to make it use /update/extract, which worked.  The command looked like this:

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update/extract -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar "C:\documents to index"
```

Comment: I tried passing the -Durl parameter and here is the error i get now;

Command - `java -Dc=gettingstarted -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract -Dtype=application/pdf -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar scandocs/`

Error - 
`SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8983/solr/u
pdate/extract`

Comment: Your URL is missing the "gettingstarted" part which specifies which "core" to upload the documents to.  The update/extract endpoint is part of the specific core, not part of the Solr root dir, otherwise you wouldn't be able to have different cores with different sets of documents.  The URL should be `http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update/extract`